# Tableau Build Parameter That Selects Different Bin Dimensions. The Goal is to have one visualization that could show 3 different Histograms

Tags: histogram, tableau-api, bin

I have three different measures and 3 different bin fields using Tableau's "Bin Feature" based on those different measure fields. When I try to build a calculated field that would tie those bins to a parameter, I get the error "cannot use numerical bin" type in CASE expression. My goal here is to create a drop down that allows the users to see 3 different histograms, which requires the creation of 3 different bin fields.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to create a parameter that'll let you select one of the three measure-bins to show a histogram?

Comment: Hi, yes! This question was poorly written, sorry about that. I believe I figured it out those by creating 3 bin calculations manually (rather than using Tableau's bin feature), you can create a parameter that will reference the manually created bins. Thanks!